# Create different messages or there is some sort of filtering in Masstransit

Tags: masstransit

We are migrating to masstransit in our distributed systems.

Our integration partners create orders on our system and they get Order_Id.

Once the order is processed we publish a message (OrderStatusChanged) that contains the Order_Id, Status ... etc

However by publishing the message, all our partners receive this message even though it was intended for one of them only.

The only solution we can think of is to create different messages for each integrated application. But the number of integrated apps is huge and growing.

Is there a way to filter messages or maybe different architecture to overcome this challenge?

Comment: In your system, are integration partners integrating directly with the broker and sending/publishing messages in the same namespace (or virtual host) as your applications? That might be a concern, honestly, as it couples them to any changes you make in your system. I'd need to understand the details to respond with anything more specific.

Comment: @Chris What I mean by integration partners is other services that are part of the organization, they issue an order to our application via API calls (though we are migrating this also to use event bus) and we process the order asynchronously then notify them via event bus. The question was not all of them should be notified only the one issued the order. From Alexey's answer I understood that we should use send instead of publish to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you are publishing messages. The publish-subscribe pattern is the behaviour that youobserve - one message is delivered to all subscribers to that message type (MassTransit uses typed-based routing).

You need to send messages instead, so you can specify the endpoint that will receive the message, explicitly. It works like this:

```
public async Task SendOrder(ISendEndpointProvider sendEndpointProvider)
{
    var endpoint = await sendEndpointProvider.GetSendEndpoint(_serviceAddress);

    await endpoint.Send(new SubmitOrder(...));
}
```

Here is the link to our documentation, the part about publishing versus sending messages: https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/producing-messages.html